# Problems understanding "connectedness"

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm starting a foray into complex analysis, and I've come across the term "connected." I've vaguely heard the term before, but the book ("Complex Variables and Applications, 9th edition" by Brown and Churchill) defines it as a set for which all pairs of points can be connected by a polygonal line that lies wholly within the set. This seemed a tad arbitrary, insufficiently applicable, and difficult to prove, so I looked up a different definition which said that a set is connected if it cannot be expressed as the union of multiple disjoint open sets. My problem involves the following counterexamples:

Let A be a subset of the complex plane that is an open ε-neighborhood about a point in the complex plane.

Let B be a subset of the complex plane that can be expressed as the union of two disjoint closed ε-neighborhoods about two different points in the complex plane.

By the polygonal line definition, B is clearly not connected while A is.

But if we assume the open set definition means that there are not multiple disjoint open sets that can be unionized into the full set, that means both B and A are connected, because B is a closed set, as it is a finite union of closed sets, and by the definition of a topology, all topologies (including the standard one) of the complex plane are closed under countable union, so B cannot be expressed as a union of open sets, disjoint or otherwise.

But if we assume the open set definition means that there are not multiple disjoint open sets that can be unionized into a SUBSET of the full set, then while A is now no longer connected, B clearly isn't either.

Basically, how do I reconcile this seeming contradiction?

Comment: I think you have things backwards. $B$ is connected by the polygonal line definition, while $A$ isn't.

Comment: Basically what your book is relying on is the fact that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, an open set is connected if and only if it is path connected.

Comment: Yes, I had those mixed up. But in the topological definition, I can't find a way to parse the definition so that B is connected while A isn't.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics If you haven't yet studied topology then the definition of connectedness in the general, topological case can be a little too harsh to swallow. That's why, apparently, that book you quote gives the much easier to grasp, down-to-Earth definition of path connectedness.

Comment: I know enough topology that I can parse it with sufficient explanation: it seems fairly straightforward. There just seems to be something I'm missing here.

Comment: I edited the question so that you're talking about the correct example when you say $A$ or $B$; please re-edit if I've made a mistake interpreting your intentions or missed a place where I should have switched an $A$ to a $B$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your misunderstanding comes from thinking of the subspace as a subspace (remaining within the larger space) vs the subspace as its own sort of space.

You are right to conclude that the disjoint union of two closed balls that do not intersect is not connected. However, a single closed ball *is* connected: you must think of it as its own space. If the single closed ball is denoted $B\subseteq\Bbb C$, then by definition a subset $U\subseteq B$ is open if and only if $U = V\cap B$, for some $V$ which is an open subset of $\Bbb C$. In particular, all of $B$ is open: $B = \Bbb C\cap B$, and $\Bbb C$ is open in $\Bbb C$. You need to be thinking about writing $B$ as a disjoint union of opens *in the subspace topology on $B$*.

If your space $X$ is two closed balls $A$ and $B$ which do not intersect, then take a small open set $U_A\subseteq\Bbb C$ containing all of $A$ and a small open set $U_B\subseteq\Bbb C$ containing all of $B$ which also do not intersect (this is indeed possible). Then $U_A\cap X = A$ is open in $X$ and similarly $B$ is open, and $A\cup B = X$ expresses $X$ as a disjoint union of opens *in the subspace topology on $X$*.

Comment: Oooooooh. So the topologies I need to look at are the topologies of B and A, not C?

Comment: That's correct (well, the topology of $\Bbb C$ determines the topologies of $A$ and $B$, but you know).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

In $\;\Bbb C\;$ and other spaces, both definitions are *almost* equivalent: a space is connected if it is path-connected, which means any two points can be joined by.

In your examples, $\;A\;$ is path connected, whereas $\;B\;$ isn't, no matter what definition you choose.

What you say about subsets unionized into...is a little beyond my comprehension.

Comment: "Unionized into A/B" is my way of expressing "the union of these sets is A/B." I don't know if there's a formal definition for it.

Comment: Why would you care what happens with $\;A\cup B\;$ ?? There is not actual, direct and general relation between this union and the fact that $\;A,B\;$ are o aren't connected. What is true is that if $\;A,B\;$ are connected **and their intersection** isn't empty then their union is connected as well.

Comment: I'm not caring about A union B or any other relationship between the two set. I'm caring that while A clearly doesn't look connected but B does, I can't parse the topological definition of connectedness in a way such that A is not connected while preserving the fact that B is connected.

Comment: There are examples of connected (sub)spaces (even within $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$) which are not path connected, for example the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Comment: @Stahl Thank you very much, of course you're right. Answer edited.

Comment: So is B connected, despite not being path connected?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics Sorry, I had a typo. Now it is corrected. And $\;B$\; isn't connected and isn't path-connected, either.

Answer (score 0):

"Let B be a subset of the complex plane that can be expressed as the union of two disjoint closed ε-neighborhoods about two different points in the complex plane. "

$B$ can be written as the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets in the *subspace topology*.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different type of connectedness - you have only mentioned 2, but I think it is clearer if I state all three.

1. The topological connectedness. This is the weakest.
2. A stronger one is path connectedness. ~ "Any two points can be connected by a continuous function."
3. Finally the strongest one is "polygonal-connectedness". ~ "Any two points can be connected by a polygon"

We know that in general topological spaces,

- $(3) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (1)^{\dagger_1}$ is true.
- If a set is open, then for that set $(2)$ implies $(3)^{\dagger_2}$.

Finally, in nice spaces, (such as $\mathbb C$) if a set is open, then  $(1)$ implies $(2)^{\dagger_3}$.

$^{\dagger_1}$ see [this link](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Path-connected_implies_connected)

$^{\dagger_2}$ see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/728696/94959)

$^{\dagger_3}$ see [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected)